# Delay service call until after loops

Tags: angular, angular2-services, typescript2.0, angular5

I have a function in my component which is to **process files into an array and then upload the array to data service** by calling one of its functions.

I am parsing uploaded CSV files into an array of JSON data. In the `processFiles` function, I'm looping through the array to push data into `processedData` array. Afterwards, I called the `this.passData.pushPassedData` function from the data service to push the processed data.

The problem is `this.passData.pushPassedData` function is being **executed before the for-loops finished processing** the files, and pushing to data service only an empty array.

```js
files = []; // array to store uploaded files
processedData = []; // array to store processed JSON data

processFiles() {
    for (let file of this.files) {
        this.papaService.parse(file, {
            header: true,
            dynamicTyping: true,
            complete: (results) => {
                console.log("Detected: ", results.data);

                for (let entry of results.data) {
                    if (entry.Interface !== "") {
                        let _entry: RuleFormat;

                        _entry = {
                            abc: "xyz",
                            def: "123",
                        }
                        this.processedData.push(_entry);
                        console.log("Pushed: " + JSON.stringify(_entry));
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    }
    console.log("Pushed: " + JSON.stringify(this.processedData));
    this.passData.pushPassedData(this.processedData);
}
```

From the console, I can see that the **data is pushed into the array only after the data service function** is called.

Is there any way to make the function call wait for the for-loops?

Comment: You don't need to prefix all your question titles with "Angular 2/4/5", we can see that you have added the `angular` and `angular5` tags :)

Comment: Hahaha, my bad. Just need to give proper description of my problem backgrouns.

Comment: All G... the `angular` tag tells us that your question encompasses all versions of angular to date (but not angularJS).

Comment: Where are you invoking `processFiles` from ?

Comment: @Zze It's called from a button from HTML side. It is invoking but not in the order I want.

Comment: It just sounds like you want to put `this.passData.pushPassedData(this.processedData);` inside your `processFiles` function ?

Comment: @Zze It's already inside and is being invoked. The problem is it is being invoked before the for-loops have finished.

Comment: Does `this.papaService.parse` return anything like a promise or observable? It sounds like something in there is async.

Comment: yes it does, but it's only for **individual** files. So, I need to wait for the whole array of files to finish processing before I call the data service function.

Comment: So, could use a `Promise.All` on the return values and `.then' on the result of that (presume the return is a promise).

Comment: I am interested to see the solution with `Promise.all`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a counter in `processFiles` and increment it in the `complete` callback. You would call `this.passData.pushPassedData` when all the files have been processed:

```
files = []; // array to store uploaded files

processFiles() {

    let processedFileCount = 0;

    for (let file of this.files) {
        this.papaService.parse(file, {
            ...

            complete: (results) => {
                processedFileCount += 1;

                for (let entry of results.data) {
                    ...
                }

                if (processedFileCount >= files.length) {
                    // All files have been processed
                    this.passData.pushPassedData(this.processedData);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```